# Clicking on push notification in android generated by AWS SDK for Unity not opening app

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SNS SDK for Unity to receive push notifications in android and ios devices. I was able to get the notifications working in both but in android devices clicking on the notification does not open the app.

The codebase is more than 2 years old. Also, I am not familiar with java. 
Based on my understanding the Utils.java file contains the implementation for notification's tap action. They have hardcorded the title to empty string so I don't get title in the notification. But I am not sure about the reason for application not opening when the notification is clicked.

> 1. Utils.java

```
package com.amazonaws.unity;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity;

public class Utils {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public static void showNotification(Context context, String contentTitle,
            String contentText) {
        // Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UnityPlayerProxyActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context.getApplicationContext());
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.setContentText(contentText);
        builder.setContentTitle(contentTitle);
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        builder.setSmallIcon(res.getIdentifier("app_icon", "drawable",
                context.getPackageName()));

        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    public static void showNotification(Context context, String contentText) {
        showNotification(context, "", contentText);
    }
}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.amazonaws.unity"
      android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

  <supports-screens
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true"/>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

  <permission android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


  <application
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
      android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:debuggable="true">

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        <category android:name="com.amazonaws.unity" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.GCMIntentService" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: This sort of looks like you want someone to debug this code for you. That's unlikely to happen. Can you reduce this to a [mcve] with a description of the specific problem so it is clear what you need? Also, remember that SO is not a thread forum, so it's best to stick with a single question at a time.

Comment: @jdv I have updated the question